Using two columns to match and return maximum value of two different columns in Google Sheets
Still new to Google sheets formulas so I'm hoping this community can provide some insight. Here's a sample sheet (I've highlighted the cells of interest) to show the results I'm hoping to get:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aafxeyQraw-Biw-eG9k-xwhDx6HVYSLmuyD9dFRIDFQ/edit?usp=sharing
Each row is a student with a unique ID number. All Student IDs in the course will in Col A and their corresponding quiz score will be in Col B. Some students will choose to retake their quizzes, so their retake scores will be entered in Col F. However, not all the students will retake their quizzes.
I want Col C to return the max value from Col B & F (thereby always returning the maximum quiz score no matter the retake score), but only if Col E matches Col A. This way, I will have Col A with all Student IDs from the course and Col C with all corresponding maximum quiz scores earned to put into the gradebook.
I'm not sure if there's a way to do this. I've tried =IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$200,A)=0,B2," ") to get the original scores matched to the correct student ID number but am not sure how to get maximum (or even retake value) to match if a retake was taken.

Looks like the sample sheet you linked isn't visible.


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,max(offset(Σ,,1),xlookup(Σ,E:E,F:F,)))))



This worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.
